# How to input text into a php array based on the text formatting

Tags: php, arrays, text

I have a text document that is opened and read by php that looks like this

```
ABC: 123

DEF: 456

GHI: 789
```

So basically it is one piece of text ended with a colon, followed by another piece of text. To separate the lines there is a line break (i.e. " \n ")

Is it possible to have this go into an array separated by the colon and the line break? So that when I print the value it should look like this:

" ABC:123,DEF:456,GHI:789 "

Comment: those are colons, not semicolons.

Comment: @octern You're right, sorry about that. It's been a long day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is split those lines up.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $doctext);
```

Next, process those lines one-by-one, splitting out the appropriate values.

```
$output = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $line_parts = explode(': ', $line, 2); // Limit 2, in case data contains a colon
    $output[$line_parts[0]] = $line_parts[1];
}
```

Then, you can find your array in `$output`.  Note that you should also add some validation to these lines and what not, to make sure they contain the data you expect.  Also, if the lines optionally contain a space between the colon and the value, or a variable amount of whitespace, then split on the colon and use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on the value, as appropriate.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much. Real quick, for  `$line_parts = explode(': ', $line, 2);` what exactly does the 2 do?

Comment: I mentioned it in the comment, and it is referenced on the documentation for `explode()` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php.  Basically, it limits the number of values that will be returned to 2.  Suppose you had data after the first colon that also had a colon in it, such as `ABC: Some:text`.  Without the 2, you would lose `:text`, as it would be in the array at index 2.  With the 2 in there, it will be included in element 1.  You don't absolutely need this if your data is well formed, but I'd include it, just in case.

Comment: Thank you so much, as I do have some lines that include a second colon.